# Python - Can't Get Pandas and Numpy Working in Visual Studio Code or Eclipse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new to IDE's and I'm trying to take courses in Python.  No matter what I try, I cannot successfully run a python script that has import pandas and import numpy in it in either Visual Studio Code or Eclipse (running on Windows 10).  I have Python 3.8 installed, and when I try running those commands in the shell it works fine. I suspect when I try executing an actual Python script instead of using the console, it might be using a different interpreter, and I only get errors when I try doing this, saying numpy is not defined.  I also get the error "cannot import name 'numpy' from partially initialized module 'pandas' (most likely due to a circular import)" when I specify "from pandas import numpy" rather than "from pandas import *".

I am very frustrated and don't know how to fix this problem.  I've tried searching for help but not having a programming background, I don't know where to go to resolve this or how.

I also cannot get pip or pip3 to work at all to install packages.  Those commands don't get recognized.

Please help!

Comment: I would recommend using pycharm. They automate a lot of things that shoud be kinda hard for newcomers... such as virtual enviroment, pip and git.

Comment: I recommend using Jupyter Notebooks. It is very useful for learning python and working with data, data manipulation, and data visualizations.

You can run line by line, rerun specific lines after making changes, and it's inline output is very useful for debugging and visualizations.

You can get it from here https://jupyter.org

Comment: Which interpreter/Python installation is VSCode using? What about when you execute the program from the terminal?

Comment: In Visual Studio Code, press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and enter `Python: Select Intepreter`?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Jupyter Notebooks/pycharm(IDE). Both are very useful for learning python and working with data, data manipulation, and data visualizations.

- PyCharm knows everything about your code. Rely on it for intelligent code completion, on-the-fly error checking and quick-fixes & easy project navigation.
  While
- Jupyter Notebooks can run line by line, rerun specific lines after making changes, and it's inline output is very useful for debugging and visualizations. You can get it from https://jupyter.org.
- Zepellin Notebooks can also serve as alternatives.